# How to close WebView after 5 seconds?

Tags: java, android

I have code for finishing TestActivity after 5 seconds:

```
package com.sda.sqlite;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestingActivity extends Activity {

    WebView view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TestingActivity.this.finish();
            }       

        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

But TestingActivity won't close in 5 seconds. If I delete loading of Google, then Activity closes successfully. Where have I made mistake?

Comment: in your code , i cant see timer.start(); ???

Answer (score 0):

Try calling stopLoading() method on the WebView before calling finish() on the TestActivity

```
@Override
public void run() {
     view.stopLoading();
     TestingActivity.this.finish();
}
```